# Webhook URL Live Won't Save

Tags: url, live

I'm trying to add a webhook url to the live version of my app and it seems to save fine.  But when I refresh the page it moves that url over to the sandbox section.  I have a valid live ID on the page so I think all approval etc is ok.

Comment: Also, I can't edit or delete URLs even in the sandbox.  I get invalid Resource ID when editing and just an unknown error when trying to delete.

Comment: Update:  When I use the rest api i'm seeing no webhooks for sandbox credentials and all of them when using live credentials.  Maybe the web UI is just bugged.